# How to overload a structure operator that accesses a class attribute?

Tags: c++

I want to overload the + operator in a struct to implement a concatenation operator. To do so, I need to access some class members(`matrix` and `route`) that the struct is inserted in, as it is shown in the code below.

**MLP.h**

```
class MLP{
     private:
          std::vector<int> route;
          std::vector<std::vector<tCost>> cost;
          double **matrix;

     ...
}
```

**Structures.h**

```
typedef struct subsequenceCost{
     int w;
     double t;
     double c;

     int first,
         last;

     subsequenceCost operator+(const subsequenceCost& other) const{
          return subsequenceCost{
               w + other.w,
               t + matrix[route[last]][route[other.first]] + other.t,
               c + other.w*(t + matrix[route[last]][route[other.first]]) + other.c,
               first,
               other.last,
          };
     }
}tCost;
```

I've already tried to `extern` the MLP object that i will use and declare the `subsequenceCost` structure as a `friend` so I could access its private members, but it was no use since MLP is a composition of `tCost`. Any ideas on how could I do it?

Comment: fwiw the common arguement against using `operator+` for concatenation is that `+` is expected to be commutative while concatenation is not.

Comment: I dont understand what is the relation between `MLP` and `subsequenceCost`. Whose operator needs to access what member?

Comment: Please don't use `typedef struct` in C++. It is necessary in C, but redundant in C++. Just write `struct subsequenceCost { ... };` or `struct tCost { ... };` and use the one name consistently.

Comment: The subsequenceCost struct operator+ needs to access the `MLP` class `matrix` and `route`

Comment: I would have a method in `MLP` like `tCost MLP::concatenate(const tCost& one, const tCost& two) const;` . It's clearly an operation involving three objects, and putting it into a "parent" object seems most logical to me.

Comment: `matrix` is a non-static member of `MLP`. *Which instance's `matrix`* do you want to refer to? The `subsequenceCost` instance does not contain any reference to a `MLP` instance.

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818, which C++ operator would you choose for concatenation? Would `*` be a better choice?

Comment: Igor's suggestion is good. Another option is to add an extra variable `MLP *myParentMLP` to the tCost structure that points to its parent MLP object. Each time you create a tCost and add it to an MLP object's cost vector, you'd have to set the extra variable, so that later the tCost can access `myParentMLP->matrix` etc.

Comment: I want to refer to the `MLP` `matrix`. How could i refer to a `MLP` instance?

Comment: @Evg none. operator overloading is great when it is obvious what the operator does and when there are no surprises, if those two conditions are not true  a method with a meaningful name is better

Comment: @JoãoWallace *Which* `MLP`'s `matrix`? A class has many instances and you need to decide which instance you want to refer to. Are you intending to call `operator+` only on instances of `subsequenceCost` inserted into the `cost` vector member of a `MLP` instance and you want `matrix` to refer to that specific instance of `MLP`? If so the suggestions above to move the function to `MLP` is a good one. What should happen otherwise if `operator+` is called on a `subsequenceCost` instance not part of the `cost` vector of a `MLP` instance??

Comment: @Evg consider that `a + b` is in some sense is just syntactic sugar for `a.operator+(b);`. If the operation isnt `+` then I dont see the advantge of calling it `+` rather than `concatenate`

Comment: @walnut Yes, I intend to use only inside of a `MLP` instance. I created a method as Igor suggested, but i would prefer an operator for the easier usage.

Comment: I suggest you add an example of how you want to use the class and operator overload to the question.

Comment: @walnut I will use a `subsequenceCost` inside of the `MLP`(I should've informed that it stands for Minimum Lantency Problem) instance to compute the minimum route cost for a certain neighborhood structure. And to get the route cost, I need to concatenate some subsequences in a certain order until i get to a full route.